# replacing only part of matched pattern in sed

Tags: bash, regex, sed

For tens of thousands of lines with the same structure, i want to go (e.g.) from here:

```
abcd 12345 qwerty asdfg
```

...to here:

```
abcd 12345,qwerty asdfg
```

...with

```
sed 's/[0-9]\ [A-Z]/,/g'
```

I can match the rigth space plus both its surrounding characters (5 q), but in the replacement i get (obviously):

```
abcd 1234,werty asdfg
```

Also, i'd prefer to perform this in the linux shell

How could i match and replace for each and every line only that space which is preceded by a digit and followed by an alphabet letter? would you suggest me another tool (or even approach) instead to get this done?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try:

```
$ echo 'abcd 12345 qwerty asdfg' | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]) ([[:alpha:]])/\1,\2/g'
abcd 12345,qwerty asdfg
```

Notes:

1. We added `-E` to get extended regex syntax.
2. `[:digit:]` and `[:alpha:]` are used in place of `0-9` and `A-Z` in order to be unicode safe.
3. Parens are used to create groups and we can reference in the replacement text.  In our case, `\1` references the number and `\2` references the letter.

Comment: This was a really clear explanation of the various bits of the solution.

Comment: in my case, capturing groups have to be escaped to work correctly: `s|\(anything\)|\1|g`, or else I have error message: `sed: -e expression #1, char 73: invalid reference \1 on \`s' command's RHS`

Comment: @user11153 Try `sed -E  's|(anything)|\1|g'` (with upper-case `E` in `-E`) instead of `sed 's|(anything)|\1|g'`.   The `-E` option turns on "extended regular expressions" which eliminates the need for those backslashes.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is as clear as ryantuck indicated. I think it could be a bit misleading, so let me clarify. The \1 refers to the whatever is between the first set of parenthesis, and has nothing to do with the fact that what is in parenthesis is [[:digit]]. So it is the parenthesis, not anything to do with the square brackets, that the \1 refers to.  Likewise, \2 refers to what gets specified by the second set of parenthesis.  Also, from my reading, -E may be documented in bsd sed, undoc'ed in GNU sed (GNU sed doc's -r instead), and if -r is used, parenthesis may need to be escaped.

Comment: @TOOGAM Your observation about options was true some years ago but the `-E` option is now [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html) for GNU sed.